# NoSQL vs. SQL when scalability is irrelevant

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql

Recently I have read a lot about different NoSQL databases and how they are being effectively deployed by some major websites out there.  I'm starting a project in which I think the schema-free nature of a database such as MongoDB would be tremendously useful.  Everything I have read though seems to indicate that the main advantage of a NoSQL database is scalability.  Is choosing a NoSQL database for the schema-free design just as legitimate a design decision as that of scalability?

Comment: its not an answer to your question, but it maybe still interesting to read article and comments to it: http://developers.slashdot.org/story/10/03/28/1432234/Why-Some-Devs-Cant-Wait-For-NoSQL-To-Die

Comment: It is nothing new, Berkeley DB is essentially a key-value store that has been around forever. Choose your tools wisely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, sometimes RDBMS are not the best solution, although there are ways to accomodate user defined fields (see XML Datatype, EAV design pattern, or just have spare generic columns) sometimes a schema free database is a good choice.

However, you need to nail down your requirements before choosing to go with a document database, as you will loose a lot of the power you may be used to with the relational model

eg...

If you would otherwise have multiple tables in your RDBMS database, you will need to research the features MongoDB affords you to accomodate these needs.

If you will need to query the data in specific ways, again you need to research what MongoDB offers you.

I wouldnt think of NoSQL as replacement for RDBMS, rather a slightly different tool that brings its own sets of advantages and disadvantages making it more suitable for some projects than others.

(Both databases may be used in some circumstances. Also if you decide to go down the route of possibly using MongoDB, once you have researched the websites out there and have more specific questions, you can visit Freenode IRC #mongodb channel)

Comment: And don't forget to consider the reporting you will need to do on your datbase. People often choose tools for the application forgetting that there will be need to do management reporting on many things.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of other conditions that I've been hearing about with non-relational systems vs relational. I prefer this terminology over sql/no-sql as I personally think it describes the differences better, and several of the "no-sql" servers have sql add-ons, so anyway.... what sort of concurrency pattern or tranaction isolation is required in your system. One of the purported differences between rel and non-rel dbs is the "consistent-always", "consistent-mostly" or "consistent-eventually". Relation dbs by default usually fall into the "consistent-mostly" category and with some work, and a whole lot of locking and race conditions, ;) can be "consistent-always" so everyone is always looking at the most correct representation of a given piece of data. Most of what I've read/heard about non-rel dbs is that they are mainly "consistent-eventually". By this it means that there may be many instances of our data floating around, so user "A" may see that we have 92 widgets in inventory, whereas user "B" may see 79, and they may not get reconciled until someone actually goes to pull stuff from the warehouse. Another issue is mutability of data, how often does it need to be updated? The particular non-rel db's I've been exposed to have more overhead for updates, some of them having to regenerate the entire dataset to incorporate any updates.

Now mind, I think non-rel/nosql are great tools if they really match your use case. I've got several I'm looking into now for projects I've got. But you've got to look at all the trade offs when making the decision, otherwise it just turns into more resume driven development.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should choose NoSQL datastore for its schema free design. Schema free design always existed in RDBMS via XML and some databases have good XML support. It is a lot easier to deal with a database than a NoSQL datastore. Scalability and big data should be the primary drivers to choose a NoSQL datastore otherwise the tradeoff of ACID and SQL is a lot to switch to NoSQL.

Answer (score 2):

the most important things should be noticed to distinguish between No-SQL and SQL 
which is :
NO-SQL useful when data base scales in a huge manner like social network 
for example :
Stack Overflow: each question has multiple answers and not imaginary an answer without question, so No-SQL will ensure that each question include it's answers 
as a result when needing getting answers of a question we can bring all answers without joining.Because join is the most expensive query in related database
thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

what raised this issue that if you have a large server farm and need to manage the distribution of your data and load balancing which is more difficult and harder to implement using RDBMS and requires high IT skills to design, plan and deploy for your solution (and still performance is less).
but if you have only 3 or 4 servers with small project. I don't think you have an issue about it. NoSQL database is usually considered in large server farms not small number of servers