# XML or MYSQL.Which should be used for storing connected data?

Tags: mysql, xml

i am writing code for friend list and messaging system for my college website.I need to store interconnected data.. need to search them ...It has about 3500 records..So which way I proceed MYSQL or XML ..which is fastest..which is best ?why?

Comment: depends on the data. Give more information: the structure of data, how it will be connected, which "queries" will be most used, do you plan also to write to the data ?

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want to store 3500 records in an XML file.

Comment: We're very wary of the word "best" on Stack Overflow... can you give more specific metrics? "Fastest" is a start, but even more specificity would be good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use one of my professor's favorite answers here: "it depends."

XML and MySQL have very different applications. If you need to be doing lots of simultaneous queries for all sorts of sophisticated things, MySQL is your clear winner. Sometimes MySQL can be hard to use in some applications because you must first create a database schema in which to fit your data. It sounds like though, that you have many records with the same structure, and it would be easy enough to throw them into a database. With a SQL based database engine like MySQL, you can also construct queries using the standard SQL language. Database optimizations can also help to increase the performance of these types of queries, for example, you can used indexes and keys. If your data needs to be updated regularly, than MySQL will likely provide better performance as it will not have to rewrite the XML file. If you need your application to scale to many simultaneous connections of sophisticated queries, you are definitely going to want to go with some sort of SQL solution.

Depending upon your application though, sometimes there are other ways to store and access your data. I for one once needed to create a persistent data structure on the disk which could be accessed very quickly, but never updated. For that, I used [cdb](http://cr.yp.to/cdb.html). There are also other database systems out there like the [Berkeley database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB), and some No-SQL solutions such as [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home). I posed a somewhat [interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534408/nosql-vs-sql-when-scalability-is-irrelevant) here on stackoverflow on the use of No-SQL solutions a little while back which you may find interesting as well.

This is really just a sampling of different considerations you may want to make when you are choosing how you want to store your data. Think about questions like: How frequently will things be queried? or updated? What will your queries look like? What kinds of applications do you need to access your information from? etc.